# laravel orm : not converting null values to column default value of column type in 5.4 version

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4

i used to work with laravel 5.2 now i've upgraded to 5.4 
i usually use my validation to pupolate object befor sending it to database like

```
$validation_rules  = ['title'=>'required' , 'number'=>'present|int'];
// do validation 

$obj = new Object();
foreach($validation_rules as $k=>$v )
$obj->$k = $request->input($k);
```

now if the user doesnt send the `number` parameter it would be null or false in the nnumer property of my object ... in the older versions it would automaticly change to default value of that column ... for example if i have `number` column type as `int` when inserting this object the `number` column would be `0`

but now this doesnt happen instead im getting this error

```
 Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'number' cannot be null
```

btw strict mode is off

**pleas note i know all about nullable , i dont want to make those fields nullable thats the whole point... its about automatically converting null values to the default column type value when field is not nullable**

Comment: in your migration have you check if the field contain nullable ? like `$table->integer('number')->nullable();` ?

Answer (score 3):

In Laravel 5.4 the concept of `->default(0)` is different than from Laravel 5.2. In 5.4, the default only works if you don't pass anything, so when you do

```
$obj->$k = $request->input($k);
```

if `$request->input($k)` is `null`, you are sort of 'inserting' `null` into a column that is not nullable, which causes the error.

So it seems you have to make the column nullable in the DB and do a check in your controller:

```
$obj->$k = $request->input($k) ? $request->input($k) : 0;
```

Comment: thanx , i hope this is not the case (at least there is an option to turn this on/off)  ... i mean why it's seems so unnecessary

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your column 'number' is nullable. If you are using Laravel migrations to create your table, you will need to add it as `$table->integer('number')->nullable();`